# How to Compile behaviour of an object at runtime c++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compilation, virtual-machine

I am designing a game where the behaviour of pieces can be encoded in a string of characters/bytecode. These are then modifiable by the user to create new behaviours at runtime. The problem comes with actually giving the pieces the behaviour the suer wrote down.

I could have an interpreter that interprets the behaviour expression and the piece would work, but its too slow for an AI to use, just due to interpreters being slow. Similarly, I could have a VM, but I was wondering if it possible to simply compile the behaviour expression into executable code that can be added to the program once the user has saved the expression. That way, I don't lose any performance later for the AI, once the pieces are being used, as it should be close to native performance. My question is how you would do something like this in C++ specifically.

Its not really able to create and implementation for every single possible behaviour, so strategy pattern is out the window too.

Maybe there is an obvious answer to the question as to how to do it, but I haven't found a comprehensive explanation anywhere on SO, so thanks in advance for any advice.

Edit: I have been made aware that what I'm looking for is a JIT compiler embedded inside my C++ application. This is helpful to know, but I don't even know where to start with this either.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How you would go around compiling code and adding ito an existing executable at runtime, if thats even possible.

Comment: you seem to be looking for a scripting language. I think lua is often used for plugins, but I am not really into this. You should clarify the question to actually ask a question. If it turns out you are looking for a library or scripting language the question is offtopic unfortunately.

Comment: I have clarified the question - I wish to do this in C++ while not losing much or any performance - quite unrealistic I know, but if not that, then the next best thing.

Comment: Are you asking about JIT (Just In Time compilation)?

Comment: @MarekR Possibly; do you think this would be a solution for this - if so, do you mind explaining it and how one might implement it?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I guess that would work, but as you pointed out, it is a bit dodgy and definitely a hacky solution. I'm now looking at a JIT compiler library for c++ (not one to compile c++ code at runtime, but one to compile expressions into machine code with c++ bindings). Would you say this is a possibility too?

Comment: JIT compiler ... [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), FYI: [LuaJIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaJIT)